# Remove double quotes from json on specific key value

Tags: php, json

I have a json file that is structured like below. I need to remove the double quotes from the source "value"

```
{
    tags:[
        {
            name: "video",
            cssanimate: "flipInY",
            source: "{ mp4: '1.mp4' }"
        }
    ]
}
```

**I need it to be:**

```
{
    tags:[
        {
            name: "video",
            cssanimate: "flipInY",
            source: { mp4: '1.mp4' }
        }
    ]
}
```

I thought maybe I could do something with preg_replace but only for the "source key". Is something like this possible?

```
$json = json_encode($records, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$json = preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*/', '$1:', $json);
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Those examples don't look like JSON. Where do you get the value of `source` in the first place?

Comment: rebuild $records correctly

Comment: Looks like `source` might be a json encoded string inside of the json, so just rebuild the array and decode `source`.

Comment: Hey guys. Thank you for the replies! @aynber here is how I am building it. https://codeshare.io/2jE3Mv Anyway to do it from while loop? Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, it looks like the json is stored in the source field in the database. Sure, you can easily manipulate the values of `$row3` before you insert it into `$records3`.

Comment: @splash58 maybe you could help me out too :) https://codeshare.io/2jE3Mv I really appreciated it!

Comment: @code_secret show result of `var_export($records3);`

Comment: @splash58 https://codeshare.io/G8o9WA

Comment: @code_secret how your source=>null turn into  "{ mp4: '1.mp4' }" ?

Comment: @splash58 In my database column "source" I have it as { mp4: '1.mp4' }

Comment: Which isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @code_secret how you fill it in DB?

Comment: @splash58 manually

Comment: @code_secret it is vary bad practice. use `json_decode(['mp4'=> '1.mp4']);` and ets. Else you will write program for each entry

Comment: @splash58 Thank you! Where does this go? I'm a little confused. I understand. I will be using this for a simple task. Thank you for all your help so far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an already-encoded json in the source field of your database, so you just need to manipulate it before you put it in the array:

```
$records3 = array();
while ($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
    $records3[] =
        array('tags' =>
                  array(
                      'name' => $row3['name'],
                      'cssanimate' => $row3['cssanimate'],
                      'source' => json_decode($row3['source'])
                  )
        );
}
```

Comment: json_decode will return false if the string really contains single quotes

Comment: @aynber thank so much! I feel like this is so close but source is returning "null" weird? https://codeshare.io/anMLyn

Comment: @aynber, replace single to double quoptes before decode

Comment: Huh. Actually, the json inside of source is invalid. It should look like `{"mp4":"1.mp4"}` instead of `{ mp4: '1.mp4' }`. Note the double quotes around the key/value. How is the data being put into the database?

Comment: @splash58 It needs more than that, since the key is missing the quotes as well. I'd be hesitant to just do a replace since it might break other strings.

Comment: You're going to have to fix how you're inserting it, so you can get it back out properly.

Comment: @aynber so close! I did manage to get it to almost work with your help but why are my "[" and "]" missing? Check it out here... https://codeshare.io/5RJP4V

Comment: Because `tags` is a single array, not multiple arrays. If you want it like that, then you'll need to add another array structure between tags and the row values. `array('tags'=> array(array('name'....)));`

Comment: BINGO! You rock! I just learned so much from this post. Thank you so much! @splash58 you too! I really appreciate it!!!